# Graphing scientific data in LineChart from MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to draw graphs (especially `LineCharts`) in my App.

To draw a `LineChart` with the mentioned library first we need to create entries and labels as follow:

```
    // Getting LineChart
    LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    // Creating list of entry
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    // Creating labels
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Fill entries and lables
    entries.add(new Entry(326.422f, 0));
    entries.add(new Entry(8.36f, 1));
    entries.add(new Entry(6.5f, 2));
    entries.add(new Entry(2.37f, 3));
    entries.add(new Entry(18.13f, 4));
    entries.add(new Entry(9f, 5));

    labels.add("0");
    labels.add("1");
    labels.add("2");
    labels.add("3");
    labels.add("4");
    labels.add("5");

    // Create dataset
    final LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "Legend description");

    // Create LineData with labels and dataset prepared previously
    LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);

    // Set the data and list of labels into chart
    lineChart.setData(data);
```

Ok this is working, but the point is what if I want to graph a set of coordinates like this: `X = {(35.3, 22.9), (69.39, 27.36), (66.37, 31.697), (58.36, 36.32), (45.336, 38.296), (25.39, 40), (67.396, 43.633)}`.

The constructor of `Entry` accepts a float number as first parameter and an integer as second parameter, so how can I give the above `X` set to the `LineChart`?

Someone could say that I can set the labels accordingly, for example the first label could be labeled as "22.9", the second as "27.36", and so on... But this is mathematically wrong as the graph is not scaled properly.

In the documentation I found classes like `Entry`, `BarEntry`, `BubbleEntry`, `CandleEntry` but there is nothing something like `LineEntry`.

Can anyone point me to the right direction on how to achieve this goal?

Thank you,

HSB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently **only integers are supported for the x-axis**. The reason therefore is that each string on the x-axis should correspond to a value on the y-axis.

**This will change** in the next [release](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases) of the library, where both values will be changed to `double`.

The new version should be released in April.

Comment: Looking forward to it! For this implementation are you working on branch called "remove_xindices"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just created the new branch.

Comment: Hello Philipp, any updates on this issue? Thank you very much.